# How to find the antiderivative of f(x).

Tags: integration, derivatives

While studying, I learned that the antiderivative of $1/f(x)$ is simply ln$\lvert f(x)\rvert$. Why is this so?

Comment: It's not so.${}$

Comment: searche in the net what antiderivative is

Comment: It is, up to constant,  the antiderivative of $f'(x)/f(x)$!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true. It is the case that $$\int\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}dx=\log f(x)+C$$
Which can be seen by making the substitution $u=f(x)$.

Comment: ... or just by differentiating both sides.

Comment: Indeed, that works